# MPI: How to ensure a subroutine is executed only on one processor on the default node?

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, mpi

I use a large-scale parallelized code, and I am new to MPI itself.

I try to run a set of shell commands from Fortran, and hence it would be entirely wasteful (and cause my results to be incorrect) if done on more than one processor.

The most relevant commands I have found are `MPI_gather` and `MPI_reduce`, but these seem problematic, because they are trying to take information from other processors and use them on the processor `0`, but I have no information that I am calling from other processors.

Basically I want to do something like this :

```
if (MPI_node = 0 .and. MPI_process = 0) then
   (execute a code)
end if
```

Comment: With `MPI` you can get the process rank `proc_rank` where `integer :: mpierror, proc_rank` and now  `call MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, proc_rank, mpierror)`. To run a code on `master` process you can do `if (proc_rank = 0) do ! your code end if`

Comment: @DOOM rather `if (proc_rank == 0) then` The same `=` vs. `==` error exists in the example code in the question.

Comment: @VladimirF yes, I did  `do`  before exclamation !!

Comment: The problem is proc_rank ==0 is not guaranteed to be on the root node - I am assuming this is the only one on which the posters set up can run shell commands and see the right files. If you need to identify one specific node you will need to know how the batch system and MPI work with each other, or leave a "marker" on the root node - a file maybe, or something telling the code the name of the root node to the program.

Comment: It shouldn't matter which node it is done on, it just needs to be ensured that the action is done only once.  Thus, so long as processor 0 is specific to one node and only one node regardless of which node it is, that is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had an issue like this. The way I solved it was to use [MPI_Comm_split](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/latest/www3/MPI_Comm_split.html) to create a communicator for each node. Something like this (C++):

```
char node_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
int name_len;
int processor_hash_id;

int global_proc_id;
int global_proc_num;

int node_proc_id;
int node_proc_num;

MPI_Comm node_comm;

//Get global info
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &global_proc_id);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &global_proc_num);
MPI_Get_processor_name(node_name, &name_len);

//Hash the node name
processor_hash_id = get_hash_id(node_name);

//Make a new communicator for processes only on the node
// and get node info
MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, processor_hash_id, global_proc_id, &node_comm);
MPI_Comm_rank(node_comm, &node_proc_id);
MPI_Comm_size(node_comm, &node_proc_num);

//Now, if you know the name of the "root node" to execute shell commands on:
if (node_proc_id==0 && processor_hash_id == get_hash_id("name-of-root-node"))
{
    //do whatever
}

//Some hash function
int get_hash_id(const char* s)
{
    int h = 37;
    while (*s)
    {
        h = (h * 54059) ^ (s[0] * 76963);
        s++;
    }
    return h;
}
```

Of course you will need to know the name of the root node.

If it doesn't matter what node it executes on, then I would suggest the following:

```
int global_proc_id;
int global_proc_num;

//Get global info
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &global_proc_id);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &global_proc_num);

if (global_proc_id==0)
{
    //do whatever
}
```

`global_proc_id==0` will only be true on one node.

Comment: This is a great answer; this is what I did and it seems to be working fine.  Thanks for answering the question one of the commenters put forward too; I think it is a highly interesting and potentially useful question to have an answer for in future research projects.  Thanks! (also love the bio)